# How to order the graph in obtained from a shelf

Tags: algorithm, math, computer-vision, graph-theory, vision

Let me describe the picture and then ask the question. So below is the shelf having three rows. Each of the numbers represents a box. The black dot represents the centroid of the box and can be represented in the $(x,y)$ coordinate. This can be seen as input. So input is the list of $(x,y)$ tuples. In this case, there are a list of 29 tuples. I wanted a programme to output the tuples in the order that is

1<< 2 << 3 <<4 ......

My initial idea is to use lexicographic ordering which is defined as follows

(a,b) << (c,d) if and only if  a< c or (a= c, b < d)

Its total ordering like that is given any two points we can tell if one is less than the other.
Now here the problem arises, so putting lexicographic ordering I can it can identify

1<< 2 but then as box 3 have a coordinate y less than 2 the order becomes 1<< 3 <<2 and so on.
I put a short code for lexicographic ordering

```
Data = [(1,1) , (2,1) ,( 1,3), (2,) ]
```

```
for i in range(len(data)):
        for j in range(i, len(data) - 1):
            if data[i][0] > data[j][0]:
                temp = data[j]
                data[j] = data[i]
                data[i] = temp
            else:
                if data[i][1] > data[j][1]:
                    temp = data[j]
                    data[j] = data[i]
                    data[i] = temp
```

Now one possible way to get around the problem is to make the boxes stacked on the shelf in horizontal alignment and then use lexicographic ordering. But the point is given input as a list of tuples coordinates it doesn't understand what is adjacent to it. So I am thinking there should be some explanation with graphs. So let's make a graph in which each node is a box and we connect two nodes if the box in the same shelf and adjacent to each other. Now if the node has a degree strictly more than 2 that could be recognised that there is a vertical stacking next to it. Hence now the ordering has to done say only with respect to $y$ ?

Please let me know how can I code this idea or any other package etc deals with a similar idea or reference.

[image]

Comment: In general there is not enough information in the input data. In the diagram a first pass could determine the shelf height and a second pass would then sort each shelf. The problem arises when, for example, there are ten boxes of equal size in five stacks of two on a shelf. The first pass would see this as two shelves.

Comment: The shelf height needs to be in the input data.

Comment: There are three shelves, so do you need the height of each shelf? I think we can just reduce to algorithm to sort each shelf and then make then assumption shelf higher is >> shelf lower

Comment: All you need to do for any given shelf is use numeric comparison, and  then a << b iff a.x < b.x or a.x = b.x and a.y > b.y

Comment: That's ordering won't work for say box 1 and it's adjacent box 2,3,4. If we use that order it will give 4<< 1<<3 <<2

Comment: I have provided a working example of the order relation in a solution.  If I have misunderstood something, then please advise.

Comment: Ideally, you’d get not only the centroid, but also the extent of each box. Then the problem is much simpler. As it stands, there is no way to know for sure if a box is on the same shelve as another box, I can come up with a counterexample for every possible assignment solution. Still, your best bet is to start with a Delaunay triangulation, which will tell you (more or less) which boxes are neighbors if each other. Then use the general direction between neighbors (approximately left-right, or approximately up-down) to determine a relative ordering between them.

Answer (score 0):

I might have misunderstood something, but if not the following is a working solution for a single shelf.

A shelf of boxes is a set of triples, (x, y, n).

The order relation, <<, on the set is then defined as:

```
a << b <=> a.x < b.x or a.x = b.x and a.y > b.y
```

Assumptions:

- Two boxes cannot be in the same position, that is, a.x = b.x -> not a.y = b.y

This can be trivially implemented in many programming languages.  For example (using a pseudogeneric syntax):

```
boxes = [ ..., (x, y, n), ... ]
boxes.sort((a,b) => 
    if a.x < b.x return a_is_before_b
    if a.x = b.x and a.y > b.y return a_is_before_b
    return a_is_after_b
)
```

The above is encoded below in javascript.

```js
function print(lob) {
    text = "";
    for ( i = 0; i < lob.length; i++ ) {
        text += '<br>' + 'Box ' + lob[i][2] + ' at (' + lob[i][0] + ', ' + lob[i][1] + ')'
    }
    return text;
}

boxes = [ [ 11.5, 3.5, 9 ], [ 9.5, 3.5, 8 ], [ 8.5, 3.5, 7 ], [ 4.5, 1.5, 4 ], [ 7.5, 2.5, 6 ], [ 4.5, 5.5, 2 ], [ 4.5, 3.5, 3 ], [ 7.5, 4.5, 5 ], [ 2.5, 3.5, 1 ] ];

function onload() {
    document.getElementById("print1").innerHTML = print(boxes);
    boxes.sort( (a, b) => { if ( a[0] < b[0] ) return -1; if ( a[0] == b[0] && a[1] > b[1] ) return -1; return 1 } );
    document.getElementById("print2").innerHTML = print(boxes);
}
```

```html
<body onload="onload()">
List of boxes before sort:
<div id="print1"></div>
<br>
List of boxes after sort:
<div id="print2"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: You are suggesting lexicographical ordering. In the question it says “My initial idea is to use lexicographic ordering […]”. OP already explained why this will not work.

Comment: The order relation as I have defined it DOES work, as evidenced by the javascript encoding. Note that it is NOT the same as the OP's order relation.

Comment: Look again at the question, and especially the drawing included. You are sorting all boxes from left to right, OP wants them sorted per shelve, and then left to right.

Comment: See OP's comment above, "reduce algorithm to sort each shelf and then make the assumption ..."